# install(FILES "${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/Abc_Win.dll" DESTINATION "Bin")

Tags: cmake, installation

Because the 'Abc_Win.dll' is shared ('dll') and needs to be copied to the target-EXE I added a custom target - like this. I'm working with MS-VisualStudio 2005-2011 and using cmake 2.8.8.

```
add_custom_target( "Abc_Win.dll" )
add_custom_command( TARGET "Abc_Win.dll" POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                    "MyDllSource/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/Abc_Win.dll"
                    "MyExeDest/${MWEB_CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/Abc_Win.dll" )
set_property(Abc_Win.dll" PROPERTY FOLDER ${MWEB_FOLDER_ADDON}/${MWEB_FOLDER_RTE})
```

All above working like I expect and the 'Abc_Win.dll' get on the right place when I build.

Now I add an the following install command - expecting 'Abc_Win.dll' in "Bin"-Directory beside my EXE.

```
install(FILES "MyDllSource/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/Abc_Win.dll" DESTINATION "Bin")
```

When I build now the CMakePredefinedTargets->INSTALL (doesn't matter which MS-StudioVersion I use) I get always a build error in the cmake generated file 'cmake_install.cmake':

- file INSTALL cannot find
- "MyDllSource/**$(Configuration)**/Abc_Win.dll"

I understand that cmake does not uses build-rules from MS-VS - like it does it for add_custom_command. It also seems to be that this cmake-file has no glue from the Content $(CONFIGRATION) which is set actual to 'Debug'.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this Problem? Help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an undocumented variable you can use here: `CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME`.

Unless you happen to have defined this yourself in your CMakeLists.txt, it will be undefined when CMake runs.

However, when you use `install` commands in your CMakeLists.txt, CMake generates a file called "cmake_install.cmake" in the root of your build tree (same place as CMakeCache.txt).  This is executed at install time, and it sets `CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME` to your current configuration in Visual Studio.

There's another slight twist; to avoid CMake expanding `${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME}` in the `install` command (it would expand to an empty string), you need to escape it with a `\`.

So, you just need to change your `install` command to:

```
install(FILES "MyDllSource/\${CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME}/Abc_Win.dll"
        DESTINATION "Bin")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Fraser - just because I'm to new I'm not allowed to increase the answer as useful. It helped and you made me very happy ;-) A small remark: For VS-Studio to find my libs with add_custom_command I still need to use 'MWEB_CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR'.

Comment: @user3208544 Glad it helped :)  And yes, `CMAKE_INSTALL_CONFIG_NAME` will be empty in the custom command since that command is executed at build time rather than install time.